# object not json serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization

While coding in python I'm getting an error: "Object of type myObject is not JSON serializable"

I tried to use some solutions I saw in other questions, but I didn't find many similarities between my code and the code in those questions, so I found it difficult to adapt the solutions in my code.

A part of my script is as follows. The error occurs in the last line of the first block:

```
import json
import os
from my_object import myObject

for a in A_set:
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
        object_name = myObject.from_json(json_data)
    else:
        object_name = myObject(a)
        object_name.property_A = property_A
        object_name.property_C = []

    object_name.property_C_add_elements(var)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(object_name.to_json(), f)
```

In another python file is defined the class of 'myObject', where is also the method 'to_json()', which I'm calling in the line of code that produces the error.

```
class myObject:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.property_A = property_A
        self.property_B = property_B
        self.property_C = []

    def property_C_add_elements(self, var):  
        self.property_C.append(var)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'Name': self.name,
            'property A': self.property_A,
            'property B': self.property_B,
            'property C': self.property_C
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, jason_data):
        object_name = myObject(jason_data['property A'])
        property_B = myObject(jason_data['property B'])
        c_list = []
        for var in jason_data['property C']:
            c_list.append(myObject(var))

        object_name.property_B = property_B
        object_name.property_C = c_list

        return object_name
```

I would be glad if I could get a solution to that problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question lacks some required data according to [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, none of the files should compile: `for a in A_set:`, `self.property_A = property_A`. Please correct the question and also add the stacktrace. And edit the question, don't add comments.

Comment: Well, it's about a long script that is reading data from an excel file and wants to convert it in json form. It's a bit difficult to produce a minimal and complete code, but I'll give a try. However the second block of code is the complete code of my second file. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you provided i can only speculate what types exactly your `property_A, property_B, property_C` variables/attributes are but

```
@classmethod
def from_json(cls, jason_data):
    object_name = myObject(jason_data['property A'])
    property_B = myObject(jason_data['property B'])
    c_list = []
    for var in jason_data['property C']:
        c_list.append(myObject(var))

    object_name.property_B = property_B
    object_name.property_C = c_list

    return object_name
```

Let's me speculate that your properties are Classinstances which have no "definition" of how they should be serialized into JSON. This is backed up by what you said :

> "Object of type myObject is not JSON serializable"

I guess the problem is with the `from_json()` classmethod, there you should probably do smth. like :

**EDITED**:

Assuming that the `__init__()` method of your Class looks as follows

```
def __init__(self, name, property_A, property_B, property_C):
    self.name = name
    self.property_A = property_A
    self.property_B = property_B
    self.property_C = property_C 
    # property_C should be a list, you may want to add validation method 
    # which checks for correct types if it is preocess cirtical
```

I suggest the following:

```
@classmethod
def from_json(cls, jason_data):
    return cls(
               jason_data['name'],
               jason_data['property A'],
               jason_data['property B'],
               jason_data['property C']
               )
```

Furthermore i suggest, if it's possible, that you change your JSON Format, provided in your `to_json()` method by simply replacing the whitespaces from "property A" to "property_A" (same for other properties). In addition you can change "Name" to lowercase "name".

Why ? Because with this format, and my changed `__init__()` method you can convert your `from_json()` to the following utilizing unpacking operation :

```
@classmethod
def from_json(cls, jason_data):
    return cls(**json_data)
```

Comment: Well, yes. The type of the error made me not to search carefully for the solution in my own code. Even the error was produced in a line that it was obvious that there wasn't any mistake. However not being familiar yet with the concept of the ool, I can make such a mistake. Now the code works properly. Thank you very much for responding, and for the time you spent.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code in the answer is even more incorrect than the one in the question.

Comment: If completely accurate: Yes i was quite superficial and hasty in the first version of my answer. I hope i clarified everything in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified (and working) version of your code.

*custom_object.py*:

```py
class CustomObject:

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        name = json_data["Name"]
        prop_a = json_data["PropertyA"]
        prop_b = json_data["PropertyB"]
        obj = cls(name, prop_a=prop_a, prop_b=prop_b)
        for var in json_data["PropertyC"]:
            obj.add_c_element(var)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, name, prop_a="", prop_b=""):
        self.name = name
        self.prop_a = prop_a
        self.prop_b = prop_a
        self.prop_c = list()

    def add_c_element(self, var):
        self.prop_c.append(var)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "Name": self.name,
            "PropertyA": self.prop_a,
            "PropertyB": self.prop_b,
            "PropertyC": self.prop_c,
        }
```

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import json
import os
from custom_object import CustomObject


def main():
    filename = "./data.json"
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("Attempting to load object from json file...")
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            try:
                obj = CustomObject.from_json(json_data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return
            print("Object: {:}\n  Class: {:s}\n  Attributes:" .format(obj, obj.__class__.__name__))
            for k, v in getattr(obj, "__dict__", dict()).items():
                print("    {:s}: {:}".format(k, v))

    else:
        print("Creating dummy object and saving to json...")
        obj = CustomObject("Object name", prop_a="object property a", prop_b="object property b")
        obj.add_c_element(1)
        obj.add_c_element("c element 2")
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            json.dump(obj.to_json(), f)
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- Corrected the errors (or added data that was missing)
- Did some renames (class, objects, attributes) for clarity
- Assumed that *prop_a*, *prop_b* are strings (not very important)
- The (main) problem was in *from_json* function (I'm not sure what you tried to do there: why so many *myObject* instantiations, when there should have been only one). Anyway, what it does now:

  1. Gets *name*, *prop_a*, *prop_b* attributes from *json_data* (which is a *dict*)
  2. Constructs the object out of the 3 values from *#1.*
  3. Read the objects for *prop_c*, and adds them one by one (if any) to the object (by calling *add_c_element*)
- Program searches for a file (with *json* contents):

  - If found, it tries to load the object from it and displays it
  - If not found, it creates a dummy object and dumps it in the file
- This is **one** (not a very nice) way of doing things. It's meant to require minimum code changes, and it's also for learning purposes. The proper (scalable, general) way would be to extend *JSONEncoder*, *JSONDecoder* ([[Python 3]: json - JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json)), but I feel that it would be a bit too advanced at this point

**Output**:

> ```py
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053914912>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Creating dummy object and saving to json...
> Done.
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053914912>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Attempting to load object from json file...
> Object: <custom_object.CustomObject object at 0x00000230B6182C88>
>   Class: CustomObject
>   Attributes:
>     prop_a: object property a
>     prop_b: object property a
>     name: Object name
>     prop_c: [1, 'c element 2']
> Done.
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. The key was finally as you say in the classmethod, and my mistake was that the attributes should take their values from json_data rather than from a new object creation. Actually that was what I wanted. But as the error occurred few lines away from that point, I missed it. About the code of the script I will have a look and I will possibly use it as a part, or as a whole. Thanks again!